# SPHINX: Indexer --rotate syntax and multiple main delta schemes

Tags: linux, sphinx, cron

I am setting up Sphinx right now and have a few questions. I have 2 different indexes with main delta schemes setup. So basicaly my conf file looks something like this:

```
source jobsmain
{...}

source jobsdelta : jobsmain
{...}

source usersmain
{...}

source usersdelta : usersmain
{...}
```

Question - I am setting up crontab to update my delta indexes every 5 minutes. My cronfile looks something like this:

*/5 * * * /usr/bin/indexer --rotate --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf jobsdelta usersdelta

Is that a valid way to have only the delta indexes updated? Or do I need to make two separate statements for each delta index? If I need to make two separate statements, is the indexer gonna be busy already fulfilling the first request? Am I gonna have to set a delay on the second request?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct syntax. Just make sure that they're updating properly, so that you can then [merge them together](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#delta-updates) later.